# form submit not working in firefox but works fine in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, firefox, form-submit

I want to submit my parent page when I click on submit button of the child page.
In my child page I've written my code as

```
string scriptString = "<script language=JavaScript> window.opener.document.forms(0).submit(); </script>";

            // ASP.NET 2.0

            if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(scriptString))
            {

                Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "script", scriptString);

            }
```

it is working fine in IE but not working in Firefox. What could be the alternate method for this?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to replace forms(0) with forms[0]

I don't think Firefox likse parentheses for arrays.