# asp.net calendar date selection not responding in firefox

Tags: asp.net, firefox, calendar, registerclientscriptblock

I have an aspx calendar that works fine in IE, however, in FF, the date selection does not respond.  When I put a breakpoint in the code behind (calActiveCal_SelectionChanged event), the application does not break into that function. So the function is not being called.

The HTML code is:

```
<td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="19">
    <asp:Calendar ID="calActiveCal" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="Silver"
        BorderStyle="Solid" CellPadding="1" CssClass="Calendar" ShowGridLines="True" OnSelectionChanged="calActiveCal_SelectionChanged">
        <TodayDayStyle CssClass="CalToday" />
        <SelectorStyle BackColor="#C0C0FF" CssClass="CalHRef" />
        <DayStyle CssClass="CalDate" />
        <NextPrevStyle CssClass="CalNavMonth" />
        <DayHeaderStyle CssClass="CalDayHead" />
        <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="Blue" CssClass="CalSelDay" />
        <TitleStyle BackColor="#C0C0FF" CssClass="CalMonthHead" />
        <WeekendDayStyle CssClass="CalWeekend" />
    </asp:Calendar>
</td>
```

**Update:**
When debugging in Firebug, I get an error message:

> window.opener.document.forms is not a function

When I search for `window.opener.document.forms` its in the C# code behind:

```
    string control = "txtDate";
    if (this.calActiveCal.SelectedDate > DateTime.Now && !this.ShowFutureDates)
    {
        this.calActiveCal.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    if (Request.QueryString.Get("c") != null)
    {
        string setting = Request.QueryString.Get("c");
        if (!setting.Equals(String.Empty))
        {
            control = setting;
        }
    }
    string strScript = "<script>window.opener.document.forms(0)." + control + ".value = '";
    strScript += calActiveCal.SelectedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    strScript += "';self.close()";
    strScript += "</" + "script>";
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Calendar_ChangeDate", strScript);
```

The strScript value is (if user selected 12/30/2011) :
`<script>window.opener.document.forms(0).txtFrom.value = '12/30/2011';self.close()</script>`

Any ideas how to get this working in FF? Unfortunately, jQuery is not an option at the moment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [form submit not working in firefox but works fine in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928783/form-submit-not-working-in-firefox-but-works-fine-in-ie)

Comment: wow.... incredible. THANKS !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace `forms(0)` with `forms[0]`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're having client-side (javascript) errors that happen only in FF and that prevent FF from even posting the request that you expect to the server. Use Firebug to see if anything gets reported to the error console.